# Checking which Availability Zone?

Tags: openshift-online-2

I see that Regions could be selected, e.g., `us-east-1`, but how could the Availability Zone be selected? If it's a lottery, how could it be checked? Is the AZ fixed over the lifetime of the gear?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see that Regions could be selected, e.g., us-east-1, but how could
>   the Availability Zone be selected?

AZ is set when you launch an instance.

> Is the AZ fixed over the lifetime of the gear?

Yes.

Comment: Isn't the Region set when an instance is launched, e.g., `us-east-1` rather than `us-east-1b`? And calling `https://[IP]/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/` doesn't return the AZ as an EC2 should.

Comment: Are you launching instances via the command-line tools?

Answer (score 0):

While the AZ is fixed over the lifetime of the gear, it is quasi-unique. Those AZs are randomized on a per account basis so your us-east-1b might be my us-east-1d for example. It is arbitrary and not worth worrying about.